# Remove unwanted data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to remove unwanted data in my record but my query is not correct. Can anyone please help me?? I want to keep records like this 'X|D_1234', 'X|D_8743' & 'X|D_0588' and i want to remove records like this 'nmy name is mary' & 'my age is 22 years old'.

```
 delete from dbo.[MEOW] 
 where (STUDENT_ID NOT LIKE 'X|D_')
```

Comment: `NOT LIKE 'X|D[_]%'`

Comment: why i need to put [] between the _ ?

Comment: Because underscores are wildcards in `LIKE` statements. e.g. `SELECT 1 WHERE 'asdf' LIKE 'a__f'` works. Using square brackets tells SQL to check for an actual underscore, not a wildcard. EDIT: If, for example, you wanted to delete 'X|D1234' because it doesn't have an underscore, then you would need to put the underscore in square brackets (or use `ESCAPE`).

Comment: ohhh thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You could find them like below

```
    delete from dbo.[MEOW] 
    WHERE STUDENT_ID NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can can do it with like command in your query like this

```
delete from dbo.[MEOW] where STUDENT_ID not like 'X|D_%'
---X|D_% will match from starting position
---%X|D_ will match from ending position
---%X|D_% will match in whole
```